# Update multiple rows at once (postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 arrays. For example :

```
let status = [1,2,3];
let name = ['Andrey','Vasya','Petia'];
let age = [23,45,54];
```

Also I have array of ids for each user which I want to update .

```
let id_list = [2323,3434,3434]
```

I want to send postgres request by which I update this data in this way by one request :

```
UPDATE users SET status = '1' , name = 'Andrey', age = '23' WHERE id ='2323'
UPDATE users SET status = '2' , name = 'Vasya', age = '45' WHERE id ='3434'
```

etc .

All data I want to update in one request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you must unnest your array:

```
WITH sample (id, name, status, age) AS (
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        --Using unnest function
        unnest(
            ARRAY[2323, 3434, 3434], 
            ARRAY['Andrey','Vasya','Petia'], 
            ARRAY[1,2,3], 
            ARRAY[23,45,54]
        )
)
--And then proceed to your update
UPDATE 
    users 
    SET status = s.status , name = s.name, age = s.age 
    FROM sample s
    WHERE users.id = s.id;
```

More info about `unnest` function [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html).

Comment: is it all one request ?